# Define a sequence $ S_n $ of real numbers by $\ S_n=\sum_\limits{i=0}^n$ $ {(\log (n+i)-\log n)^2}\over(n+i) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Define a sequence $ S_n $ of real numbers by
$\ S_n=\sum_\limits{i=0}^n$ $ {(\log (n+i)-\log n)^2}\over(n+i) $
Does $ \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} S_n$ exist? If so, compute the value of this limit. Justify your answer.

Comment: Please check if the edit is correct for your mathematical expression.

Comment: Sure sir. Will you be needing anything else?

Comment: For the OP: many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's) best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key to finding the limit is to perform a Riemann sum as follows:$$\begin{align} & \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} S_n \\ = & \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac{\{\log (n+i)-\log n\}^2}{n+i} \\ = & \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac{\{\log (1+\frac{i}{n})\}^2}{1+\frac{i}{n}} \\ = & \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \, h \sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac{\{\log (1+ih)\}^2}{1+ih}  \text{where h}=\frac{1}{n} \\ = & \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx \\ = & \int_{\log 1}^{\log 2} u^2 \, du \,\,\, \text{where u} =\log(1+x) \,\,\,\text{and du} = \frac{1}{1+x}\text{dx}  \\ = &  \frac{u^3}{3}|_0^{\log 2} \\ = & \frac{\log^3 2}{3}\end{align}$$

The limit finitely exists as you can see. And for the justification, try your bit. If you can't, then ask me.

Comment: (+1) Fine answer, but I would avoid the $\{\ldots\}$ brackets since in other contexts $\{x\}$ stands for the fractional part of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. A key word could be Riemann sum with the related function
$$
f(x)=\frac{\log^2(1+x)}{1+x}.
$$